# SQL finding duplicate values in rows

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, rows

I have table with 22 columns and multiple rows.

I want to get a new table that will contain only rows for which the values in the columns V1, V3, V4, V13 appear  twice in the table in correlation with each other (these repetitions)

Works in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I've tried something like this

```
SELECT 
    V1, V3, V4, V13
FROM  
    table 
GROUP BY 
    V1, V3, V4, V13
HAVING 
    (COUNT (*) = 2)
```

Comment: i have duplicates values in all mentioned columns

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by first counting how many values you have for each "*V1*", "*V3*", "*V4*", "*V13*" fields with the `COUNT` window function. Then join back with your original table, though keeping those rows which have count bigger than 1.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT <your_table_identifier_field(s)>, 
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY V1, V3, V4, V13) as cnt 
    FROM table
)
SELECT * 
FROM       tab
INNER JOIN cte
        ON tab.<your_table_identifier_field(s)> = cte.<your_table_identifier_field(s)>
       AND cte.cnt > 1
```

---

**EDIT**: What if there's no specific row identifier? You're forced to match all column values then.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY V1, V3, V4, V13) as cnt 
    FROM table
)
SELECT * 
FROM       tab
INNER JOIN cte
        ON tab.<field1> = cte.<field1>
       AND tab.<field2> = cte.<field2>
       AND ...
       AND cte.cnt > 1
```

Comment: Thanks but  I don't really understand what I have to provide in your_table_identifier_field (s)? Are these supposed to be the names of the other columns in the table?

Comment: among the 22 columns, do you have a field which uniquely identifies each row? @K_R

Comment: no, only the column names and values in each row

Comment: Then you need to use each field as long as each row can be uniquely identified only by the combination of all their fields. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Actually some other options may be available, but they require knowledge about the data. If you update your post with some sample data (with all columns and some rows) then I might propose another solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much and last question I was able to generate a column named id with a unique value for each row in my table but in the command: ON tab.id = cte.id it underlines tab.id in red and throws an error

Comment: change `tab` with your updated table name, and make sure your updated table has the field named `id` @K_R

Answer (score 0):

Why over-complicate things? Just take your original query, put it in a CTE and then join the CTE to the original table.

```
with cte as (
    SELECT V1, V3, V4, V13 FROM dbo.table 
    GROUP BY V1, V3, V4, V13
    HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
)
select t1.* 
from dbo.table as t1 
inner join cte on t1.V1 = cte.V1 and t1.V2 = cte.V2 ...
order by ...
;
```

I've made some changes to incorporate best practices. Added the schema name (assumed dbo) to your table name, statement terminator, ORDER BY clause (because it usually matters). I changed the HAVING clause since you asked for duplicates which means the count is > 1. Using count = 2 means you are limiting the result to those rows where there are **exactly** two duplicates. That is a very unusual requirement but change it if needed. Normally I would not use "*" as the column list as it is generally far better to explicitly include the columns you need. I leave that to you as well.

Finally, consider changing your schema to prevent duplicates. That will avoid a lot of future work.